# Install .deb on Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, debian

I recently came across [this open source compressor](http://opensource.seznam.cz/KJScompress/index.html?lang=en) that I want to use in my mac app, but it seems to be available for linux/debian.

Is there any way I could use it on mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're better off using the sourcecode and compile that for yourself.

On the other hand there are many other source compressors you might want to consider, for example Yahoo's open source YUI Compressor: http://yuilibrary.com/download/yuicompressor/

Comment: java is not preinstalled on lion. I will be using this compressor in my native mac app.

Comment: I can compile from source on mac?

Comment: Yes, same way you do that on linux...

Comment: I tried but there are a lot of "no"s. please see: http://pastebin.com/SCdTiNbE  -- should I still go ahead and make install?

Comment: errors with `make` http://pastebin.com/GW5GFSHS

Comment: Try reading through this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/intro/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way you can use this tool on your Mac (assuming you're using OS X and have no intention of installing Debian).

Download [the source](http://opensource.seznam.cz/KJScompress/download/index.html?lang=en) and build it.

You could even submit a [Portfile](http://guide.macports.org/#development.creating-portfile) to [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) to make it easier for your peers.

Answer (score 0):

As Johnsyweb states you can also compile the the source code, but to do this you have to install the development tools.

You properly find it on your install DVD as Xcode package or download it direct from Apple. 
Finally you also need the root passord to install it after using the commands "configure", "make" for installing it using "make install".